# Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)-Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I am trying to deploy a JAX-WS on a Tomcat server and get the following Console output:

```
`Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)  
 - Error listenerStart
- Context startup failed due to previous errors`
```

I believe this has something to do with how the context configuration file has been set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Context docBase="C:\Documents and Settings\tomcat" workDir="C:\Documents and Settings\tomcat\work"   path="/tomcat" reloadable="true"  />
```

or the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application     2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">   
<web-app>   
<listener>   
    <listener-class>   
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextistener
    </listener-class>   
</listener>   
<servlet>   
<servlet-name>CalculatorPublisher</servlet-name>   
    <servlet-class>   
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet   
    </servlet-class>   
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
</servlet>   
<servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>CalculatorPublisher</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/calculator</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>   
<session-config>   
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>   
</session-config>   
</web-app>
```

I could not figure out how to view the previous error(s) or if there is even a way to do that.

Comment: It's saying that something went wrong when starting the webapp up.  Have a look in the logs.  If there's nothing in the console, look at some of the logs in the Tomcat logs directory.

Comment: thanks prunge.....was able to solve the issue doing that....

Answer (score -1):

I basically checked the logs in the Tomcat logs directory to see what was actually going wrong under the hood and added the correct libraries.